# Angular 2 - can I dynamically change the styleUrl in the component?

Tags: angular

Angular 2 - can I dynamically change the styleUrl in the component?

I want to alter the CSS for a component based on a query string variable.  I can get the variable ok in the ngOnInit() func, but thats where I want to change the CSS based on this value.

Thanks

Comment: You should consider other way to handle it.

Comment: You can set dynamically css classes based on the variable with the `ngClass` directive of Angular

Answer (score 1):

You could use **ngClass** for dynamic changing.

In your .html file you could do this:

```
<div [ngClass]="dynamicClass"></div>
```

In your component.ts file you could set this variable and change it in the onInit() function:

```
dynamicClass: string = 'licolor';

ngOnInit(){
    this.dynamicClass = 'nextStyle';
}
```

---

More about ngClass to find here:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

---

**ngStyle** could maybe be a valid solution for you too.